# InnoSetup: How can you set the order of icons in the start menu?

Tags: inno-setup

I have the following `[Icons]` section in my Inno Setup script:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\IA_Desktop.exe"; WorkingDir: {app}
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\IA_Desktop.exe"; WorkingDir: {app}
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{#MyAppURL}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}
```

I would expect that the order of the icons in the Start Menu -> group would be:

```
MyAppName
MyAppUrl
Uninstall
```

But instead I get:

```
MyAppUrl
Uninstall
MyAppName
```

What settings or other code do I need to use to set the order of the icons in the group?

Thanks!

Comment: The order of the Start menu items is driven by Windows. For more info see [`this Inno Setup FAQ`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?startmenuorder) topic.